# Adding elements to Form programmatically

Tags: c#, winforms

I am writing C# code on Ubuntu and compiling using the CSC compiler as I need to use Windows.Forms
I am not using the Visual Studio IDE, only writing code in an ordinary editor.
The basic ShowDialog() function in classes that extend Form is running fine.
However, when I try to add elements to it using the Controls.Add(), the compiler is showing the following error :`SpanHelpers.Add<T>(IntPtr, int)' is inaccessible due to its protection level`
How do I access this particular function ?
And what am I doing wrong ?

My code :

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace helloWorld
{
    class first
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            FormsSample forms = new FormsSample();
        }
    }


    public partial class FormsSample : Form
    {
        private FolderBrowserDialog fbd;

        private void InitializeComponents()
        {
            this.Controls.Add<FolderBrowserDialog>(fbd);
        }
        public FormsSample()
        {
            fbd = new FolderBrowserDialog();
            InitializeComponents();
            this.Name = "Folder Browser";
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.ClientSize = new Size(1000, 500);
            this.CenterToScreen();
            ShowDialog();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Share `SpanHelpers.Add<T>(IntPtr, int)` code and other related code.

Comment: As mentioned by the others, there is no standard `SpanHelpers.Add<T>(IntPtr, int)` method and it seems to be either Your custom method or a method from some kind of library You are using. The important thing to note, however, is that if You want to show `FolderBrowserDialog`, You usually do not need to add this dialog as a child control. It may be different when using Your libraries, but You can find an example how to use this dialog here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.folderbrowserdialog?view=netframework-4.7.2#examples.

Comment: Understood. The `FolderBrowserDialog` will not get added since it is not a control and I need to use the generic Add function.

Answer (score 0):

`Control.ControllCollection` doesn't define a generic `Add<T>` method. It seems that you're somehow trying to reference a non-public extension method.

You should change your code to simply use `Add`:

```
this.Controls.Add(fbd);
```

Comment: A `FolderBrowserDialog` is not even a control.

Comment: Thanks ! This worked. I was using the template function since the error printed was directly referencing that.